# Nginx-clojure Java Handler

Tags: nginx

I am trying to capture the request body in my nginx java handler for some reason i am getting a null pointer exception. How do we capture the body in the java handler?

```
public Object[] invoke(Map<String, Object> request) {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) request.get(Constants.BODY);
        String abc = getIdFromBody(is)
        if(abc !=null)
         {  return Constants.PHASE_DONE;}
   }



private String getIdFromBody(InputStream is) {
        ObjectNode node;
        String text = null ;
        try {
             text = IOUtils.toString(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
            logger.info("requestPayload={}", text);
          
         }

         catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        logger.info("didnt get entity_id ", text);
         return text;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you use content handler so you must return normal response instead of Constants.PHASE_DONE.

Constants.PHASE_DONE is used within a non-content handler, e.g. header filter, body filter, access handler, rewrite handler.